# html tag attr regular expression in vs 2008

Tags: regex, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I would like to ask about regular expression question. I want to search the following syntax in vs 2008:

```
<table width="10%" class="test" style=""> </table> 
<table class="test" style="" width="10%">  </table> 
<table class="test" width="10%" style=""> </table> 
<table class="test" width="10%"></table> 
<table class="test"></table> 
<table></table> 
<div width="10%"></div>
```

I would like to search all width= in the above table text.

The search regular expression

```
table[^\w]+width="[^"]+"
```

after search result

```
<table width="10%" class="test" style=""> </table> 
<table class="test" style="" width="10%">  </table> 
<table class="test" width="10%" style=""> </table> 
<table class="test" width="10%"></table>
```

and i want to replace width to style="width:"

The result should be

```
<table style="width:10%" class="test" style=""> </table> 
<table class="test" style="" style="width:10%">  </table> 
<table class="test" style="width:10%" style=""> </table> 
<table class="test" style="width:10%"></table>
```

How can i make this replacement?

Comment: Generally, [regex isn't the right tool for parsing HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags).

Answer (score 0):

Use following regular expression:

```
width="[^"]+"
```

`[^"]` matches any character that is not `"`.

Comment: @user3277955, Do you want delete tags that does not have `width` attribute? Please make it clear.

Comment: i would like to replace width format to style="width:" format

Comment: @user3277955, The expected result in the question does not match your explanation.

Comment: Sorry my mistake, i updated the question to clear the requirement.